# How to generate the output in hexadecimal in Openssl?

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

Finally I am able to get the output in base64 format by using the "-a" switch; there is any hexadecimal switch that I can use?

```
echo '0: 63616e746765747468697332776f726b' | xxd -r | openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -a -K 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

If I run that code, I will get this:

```
N2+bVLU8fIS7ucFW1Qr/xwFD22PuZrDN/59pkXaAFR4=
```

...and somehow it is also wrong because it is supposed to be only this:

```
N2+bVLU8fIS7ucFW1Qr/xw==
```

Anyways, I just need to be able to come up with this output:

```
376f 9b54 b53c 7c84 bbb9 c156 d50a ffc7
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: @jww I'm programming right now and this is completely relevant to what I'm doing.  Shell scripts are still code.  The mods at Super User would likely kick this back to SO or ask the OP to repost it on the Security Stack Exchange.  The rest of us are just trying to get work done.

Comment: @Alex - Feel free to ask a question if you have one. We will judge it on its own merits.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Q1. No, `openssl enc` can't output in hex, only binary/raw or base64. But you apparently have `xxd` available, whose main purpose it to convert to hex so pipe into that, then `cut -c10-50` to remove the leftmost address and rightmost printable-ASCII parts to get the exact format you show `xxxx xxxx etc`; alternatively `xxd -p` does 'plain' `xxxxxxxx` or `od -An -tx1` does `xx xx xx xx etc` in one step.

Q2. You are getting (the base64 encoding of) two blocks of ciphertext because `enc` with a nonstream cipher defaults to PKCS#5 padding, and your plaintext is exactly one block (which is 16 bytes for AES). **Add `-nopad`** to get the output you ask for.

---

Here is the **whole thing in one place in sequence**:

PROBLEM: You have input in hex and want output in hex, but `openssl enc` takes input in binary (not hex) and produces output in binary or base64 (but not hex).

DEDUCTION: You must convert the input from hex to binary. You must also convert the output from binary to hex. Although both of these include the words 'hex' and 'binary', these are different things.

Step 1: convert the input from hex to binary, because you have hex and need binary input for `enc`

```
 echo 0: 63616e746765747468697332776f726b | xxd -r
```

Step 2: do the encryption (without padding) from binary to binary

```
 openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -nopad -K 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Step omitted: do NOT use `-a` to convert to base64. *You don't want base64.*

Step 3: Convert binary to hex, because you have binary but want hex

```
xxd -p
```

TOTAL (using minimal shell prompt of $, yours may be different):

```
$ echo 0: 63616e746765747468697332776f726b | xxd -r \
| openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -nopad -K 00000000000000000000000000000000 | xxd -p
376f9b54b53c7c84bbb9c156d50affc7
$
```

This is the result you asked for except without spacing which you later said you don't need.

If you do want the spacing use `xxd` without `-p` and add `cut` as I originally said:

```
$ echo 0: 63616e746765747468697332776f726b | xxd -r \
| openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -nopad -K 00000000000000000000000000000000 | xxd | cut -c10-50
376f 9b54 b53c 7c84 bbb9 c156 d50a ffc7
$
```